# WPF double click edit listview item label

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have a label displaying some content in listview item. When a user double clicks the label, it should enable a user to change the content.

[Check the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaeKe.png)

If user double click the first name (check the image), it should enable a user to change the first name.
Is there a simpler way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a datagrid instead of a listview.
The datagrid allows the user to edit the values when clicking them.

http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/datagrid-control/introduction/